# How to return results only if four mandatory fields exist in Solr

Tags: solr

In our scenario we receive an unknown postal address in a string format with an unknown address format. Our need is to run the search with the given postal address over all the fields and find the best match for the query.

However, if we don't have an exact match for the 4 mandatory fields - meaning SOLR returns similar results (for at least 1 mandatory field), then NO results should be displayed.

The 4 mandatory fields are BuildingNumber, LocPressName, County and PostalDistrict defined with the other search fields in the schema.xml file as follows -

```
<field name="uid" stored="true" indexed="true" type="uuid" default="NEW"/>
<field name="UnitNumber" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general"/>
<field name="UnitName" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general"/>
<field name="BuildingNumber" stored="true" indexed="true" type="exactish"/>
<field name="BuildingName" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general"/>
<field name="LocPressName" stored="true" indexed="true" type="exactish"/>
<field name="PostalDistrict" stored="true" indexed="true" type="exactish"/>
<field name="County" stored="true" indexed="true" type="exactish"/>
<field name="AddressId" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general"/>
<field name="ExchangeCode" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general"/>
<field name="PreviousCustomerName" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general"/>
<field name="Eircode" stored="true" indexed="true" type="text_general"/>
```

I am fairly new to Solr and I am not sure how to generate this query that produces the best results only if it finds a match for ALL FOUR mandatory fields.

Answer (score 0):

Without the exact type of your `exactish` field, its hard to say, but assuming that it's a StrField. The basic, explicit version:

```
q=(BuildingNumber:18 AND LocPressName:Foo AND 
County:Forthershire AND PostalDistrict:Bar) AND searchField:Query
```

.. where searchField is a field where everything you want to search as a text_general field has been copied. You can replace this with all the other fields if needed.

Another option:

```
q=Query&defType=edismax&qf=UnitNumber UnitName .. etc&fq=BuildingNumber:18 AND 
LocPressName:Foo AND County:Forthershire AND PostalDistrict:Bar
```

This works the same, but allows a free form querying by using the `edismax` query parser. The `fq` applies a filter to your resultset, where documents *has* to match the filter to be considered in the result set. It does however not affect how a document is scored.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however it seems to split the given address, which is not possible. The issue is that we receive the address as an unknown string with an unknown format.

Comment: So how do you get anything into the specific fields in your schema?

Comment: We are getting the best match from docs without any importance to mandatory fields. Meaning, mandatory fields contain values that are not related to the data from the given string (of unknown format) - I will post an example...

Comment: Example on given string - APARTMENT 8 RIVERSIDE NAVAN ROAD DUBLIN 15 D15 K796

I expect to get the following result: 
name=UnitNamer
name=BuildingNumber - 15
name=BuildingName
name=LocPressName - NAVAN ROAD
name=PostalDistrict - DUBLIN 15
name=County - DUBLIN
name=AddressId - 914202
name=ExchangeCode - BDT

Where County, LocPressName, PostalDistrict, BuildingNumber are mandatory fields extracted from the string, and the rest are optional.

Comment: However, we get:
name=UnitNamer
name=BuildingNumber - 7
name=BuildingName
name=LocPressName - NAVAN ROAD
name=PostalDistrict - DUBLIN 15
name=County - DUBLIN
name=AddressId - 914202
name=ExchangeCode - BDT

Where 'BuildingNumber' is a mandatory field with value 7 and not found in the given string (only in core docs) - acting as best match.